# SQLITE corruption?- DELETE FROM toolList WHERE toolId=".$id

Tags: php, sql, html, sqlite

something is seriously wrong with my SQLITE

I included echo $dbquery to see exactly what query is being run, and the statment seems correct - but when trying to view the db after, it comes up blank! I've checked the actuall file, and theres still data in the db file, so maybe it corrupting it?

> the query prints as: DELETE FROM toolList WHERE toolId=1289
>
> function Up($id){
>   global $dbhandle, $dbresult;
>   $dbquery = "DELETE FROM toolList WHERE toolId=".$id;
>   $dbresult = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $dbquery);
>   echo $dbquery;
>   }
>
> < a href="'.Up($data['toolId']).'">DELETE!< /a>

Thanks

Comment: You have to get yourself familiar with SQL injection attacks before you write code like this.

Comment: I understand that it's vulnerable, but it's for a prototype site.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that you corrupted a sqlite db during normal operation. Your question is a bit unclear:

- What happens if you run a select statement from the sqlite3 command line utility against your DB.
- Keep in mind that sqlite does not shrink a DB file untill you issue a vaccum command.
- Also it looks like you are running your function to display the href for the link, but the function does the delete! So if you ran this over a list of items once, then they would all be gone.